# Is there a way to use a memory mapped file as a live container for .net objects?

Tags: .net

I came across several tutorials that deal with MMF in .net. All of them adopt a similar approach though - serialize file and write in bulk as bytes and read in bulk as bytes and deserialize.

In theory though, I wouldn't need to deserialize an entire hash table for it to be operable, just a little section of it where I'm looking for the kvp. I'm thinking that I'll probably have to write a custom class to do so but just in case - Is there a way to make a .net object treat a mmf as actual ram?

Comment: Live containers usually produce dead programs.  The need to add your own locking so one program isn't reading the partially-written data produced by another program is a hard requirement anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The closest you can get is by using `unsafe` code, which gives you better control over unmanaged pointers. However, you'll need to resort to `struct`s and other "primitive" types - classes aren't supported.

However, it's hard to tell what the point of this would be - you're throwing away the whole reason why you'd use C# in the first place. Classes like `HashSet` or even `List<T>` rely heavily on automatic memory management, something you simply cannot do with `unsafe` code. Perhaps it would be a better idea to use C/C++ for that part of the code, and link it as a DLL?